# What is the correct way to create an object and push it in a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the correct way to add an object to a vector ? It seems that a vector takes a copy of the object, rather than the actual object...

For example:

```
class MyClass{
private:
  std::vector<Texture>_textures;
public:
  void addATexture(int textureWidth,int textureHeight){
      Texture tex(textureWidth,textureHeight);
      _textures.push_back(tex);//A copy of tex is pushed into in..
  } // ---> At this point, tex is destroyed...
}
```

What is the correct way to put objects in the vector, without copies ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using C++11 or later, you may want to use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to create an object in place:

```
_textures.emplace_back(textureWidth, textureHeight);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned that your object is copied when inserted into a `std::vector`, you may likewise be concerned that objects that are already in the vector are also copied when the vector is reallocated. You can prevent that undesired behavior in one of the following ways:

1. If you know the size of your collection beforehand and can postpone the creation of the object to be-inserted till right-before-insertion, then [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the `vector` and use its [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) method.
2. Otherwise, ensure that your class provides a move constructor and an equivalent of a move-assignment operator (i.e. a proper move-assignment operator or an assignment operator that takes its argument by value):

   ```
   // CAVEAT: this will compile even if Texture is not a movable type (as long
   // CAVEAT: as it is copyable)
   std::vector<Texture> _textures;
   Texture tex(textureWidth,textureHeight);
   _textures.push_back(std::move(tex));
   //                  ^^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. Or store your objects in `std::vector` indirectly, i.e. through pointers (or, better, through `std::unique_ptr`):

   ```
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Texture>> _textures;
   _textures.push_back(std::make_unique<Texture>(textureWidth,textureHeight));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Using c++11, you can benefit move constructor for costly objects:

```
  _textures.push_back(Texture(textureWidth,textureHeight));
```

Because the object you construct is a temporary one, it's move constructor will be called.

Another way is to call `emplace_back` instead of push_back:

```
  _textures.emplace_back(textureWidth,textureHeight);
```

Calling `push_back` will cost a constructor and a move, but `emplace_back` will have only one constructor.

However,  **sometimes** it's OK to have a copy. Compiler will optimize out the code if possible (But don't rely on it).

Comment: If the copy has side effect, it will not be elided

Answer (score 1):

In this you can use vector of pointer to the object.

```
class MyClass{
private:
  std::vector<Texture *> _textures;
public:
  void addATexture(int textureWidth,int textureHeight){
      Texture * tex = new Texture(textureWidth,textureHeight);
      _textures.push_back(tex);`enter code here`
  } 
}
```

But remember you will have to de-allocate memory from all the entries of the vector.

Comment: Better to use a vector of smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) if the vector is supposed to own the objects.